# Define middle column width for three column NavigationView in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Below is an example of a three column `NavigationView` in a macOS app. I defined the `minWidth` for the `Sidebar` and the `Itembar` but only the `Sidebar` respects the width value. The `Itembar` seems to ignore it. Is there a way to define the width of the middle column view (represented by the `Itembar` view)?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Group {
    let name: String
    let items: [String]
}

let groups = [
    Group(name: "Group A", items: ["Item 1", "Item 2"]),
    Group(name: "Group B", items: ["Item 3"]),
    Group(name: "Group C", items: ["Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"])
]

struct Sidebar: View {
    @State private var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(groups, id: \.self.name) { group in
            NavigationLink(group.name, destination: Itembar(items: group.items), tag: group.name, selection: $selection)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 150)
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .toolbar {
            Button(
                action: {
                    NSApp.keyWindow?.contentViewController?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)
                }, label: {
                    Label("Toggle sidebar", systemImage: "sidebar.left")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct Itembar: View {
    let items: [String]
    @State private var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink(item, destination: DetailView(detailText: item), tag: item, selection: $selection)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 100)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let detailText: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("The selection is \(detailText)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Sidebar()
            Text("Select a Group")
            Text("Select an Item")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When there's no selected item, size of middle column is calculated based on `Text("Select a Group")` placeholder, and when some item is selected - than it calculates on `List` size. So you need to set `minWidth` in both places for consistent behaviour
2. Looks like middle column has system `minWidth: 200`, so you can't override it with a lower value, only with a bigger one

```
struct Itembar: View {
    let items: [String]
    @State private var selection: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink(item, destination: DetailView(detailText: item), tag: item, selection: $selection)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: middleColumnMinWidth)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Sidebar()
            Text("Select a Group")
                .frame(minWidth: middleColumnMinWidth)
            Text("Select an Item")
        }
    }
}

private let middleColumnMinWidth: CGFloat = 300
```